# reading json file using jackson library in scala language

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I am newto the scala language to i am trying to read the json file in my scala file using jackson library

my son file is like this

```
{
  "Rice":[
    {
      "name":"Basmati",
      "price":40
    },
    {
      "name":"jeera",
      "price":30
    },
    {
      "name":"Indrayani",
      "price":40
    }
  ],
  "Pulses":[
    {
      "name":"peas",
      "price":60
    },
    {
      "name":"ground nut",
      "price":60
    },
    {
      "name":"dal",
      "price":80
    }
  ],
  "Wheats":[
    {
      "name":"atta",
      "price":40
    },
    {
      "name":"bread",
      "price":45
    },
    {
      "name":"bun",
      "price":50
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with the case classes to store and print the data
code sample like this

```
case class Inventory(var name:String,var price:String)

object InventoryDataManagement {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
      .addModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      .build()

    val src = new File("src/main/json/inventary.json")

    val myMap = mapper.readValue(src,classOf[Inventory])

    println(myMap.name)
  }
}
```

but I am getting error like below

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Rice" (class Inventory), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "price", 
"name"])
```

please help to understand this
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Unrecognized field "Rice" (class Inventory)

This error should make you notice that Jackson is looking for a field `Rice` on the `Inventory` class, which doesn't make sense.

Why so?

Because you are telling Jackson to read your JSON file as a single `Inventory` instance.

This is not what your JSON file contains, it contains something that can be represented as a `Map[String, Seq[Inventory]]`.

You should try something like this instead:

```scala
mapper.readValue(src,classOf[Map[String, Seq[Inventory]]])
```